# Whats the right way to call functions before flask app is ran?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pymongo

Hey am trying to run the listener function before the flask app is run its fucntion is to stream changes in the twitter_search collection. The problem is if i place the listener function before the app.run() then the flask app doesnt run. I need to run the flask app and handle requests as well as stream the changes. Thanks

```
@app.route("/message-actions", methods=["POST"])
def message_actions():

def background_worker(tweet_object):
    pass

def listener():
    try:
        pipeline = [{'$match': {'operationType': 'insert'}}]
        print("listener")
        with app.app_context():
            with db.twitter_search.watch(pipeline) as stream:
                for insert_change in stream:
                    print(insert_change['fullDocument'])
                    background_worker(insert_change['fullDocument'])
                    print("New tweet posted to slack channel")

    except Exception as e:
        # The ChangeStream encountered an unrecoverable error or the
        # resume attempt failed to recreate the cursor.
        print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener()
    app.run()
```

Comment: That means that `listener()` is a blocking call. Have you considered running it in a thread?

Comment: Yeah running it in a thread worked for me, thanks @Nf4r